# .pfx file contains 5 certificates, need help on how to separate each certificate in its own .pfx file

Tags: certificate, pfx

I changed pc and had to export certificates, I did it in bulk and exported them all in just one .pfx file. I need all the certificates in the personal file and in order to do so it requires that each certificate is in its own .pfx.Sadly i dont have access to my old computer to export them individually. Thank you.

Ive tried many ways but i just cant import it, it imports the certificates in the "other persons" area instead of "personal" area in the current user certificates.